# При наведении курсора на рамки объекта фоновое изображение немного двигается

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения, background

Уже второй день пытаюсь найти возможность сделать, чтобы при наведении на картинку, она условно двигалась за курсором (не выходя за изначальные свои рамки, работа с приближением). Простым языком, я хочу чтобы при наведении на грань объекта его фон чуть уменьшался и давал увидеть немного большую площадь изображения

---

Вот так до наведения на верхний правый угол

[image: Вот так до наведения на грань]

А примерно вот так после

[image: А примерно вот так после]

---

Аналогичный пример с наведением на левый нижний угол:

До

[image: Аналогичный пример с наведением на левый нижний угол]

После

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Складывается очень сильное ощущение, что я находил ранее возможность это сделать буквально одной строкой кода, а сейчас всё, что предлагают в интернете - полноценные Java-скрипты или как минимум большие прописанные условия в css. Может я пропускаю какое-то свойство для внутренней картинки или что-то подобное, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Ваша строчка :) Всё сделано с помощью изменения стилей. Высота и ширина взяты случайные.

```js
let photo = document.getElementById("photo");

photo.onmousemove = function(e) {
    let rect = photo.getBoundingClientRect();
    let percentX = (100 - (e.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width * 100) + "%";
    let percentY = (100 - (e.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height * 100) + "%";
    this.style.backgroundSize = "50%";
    this.style.backgroundPosition = percentX + " " + percentY;
}

photo.onmouseleave = function() {
    this.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0% 0%";
}
```

```css
#photo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: no-repeat url("https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/-e95qclc6pwSnGE2YccC2oLDW_8=/1200x675/2020/04/16/7d6d8ed2-e10c-4f91-b2dd-74fae951c6d8/bazaart-edit-app.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #f00 solid
}
```

```html
<div id="photo">
</div>
```

`rect` обновляю каждый раз на случай, если картинка сместится, иначе можно вынести его из события.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё прекрасно работает)